# jQuery Tools Overlay - Loading form but not passing $_POST vars?

Tags: php, jquery, post, jquery-tools

Say I have `info.php` page with user info (id, name, age, etc).

On this page, there is an 'edit' button that takes the user to a form on `edit.php` so they can change their info. The form is populated via $_POST with id, name, age, etc.

`edit.php` has an 'update' button that posts back to `info.php` with the updated data. This all works fine.

But when I try to load `edit.php` within a jQuery Tools Overlay pop-up, the form in `edit.php` appears but the variables are not passed along. Instead they all appear as 'undefined'.

I am not sure where to place the required `href` element so as to pass my variables to `edit.php` when inside the overlay.

Any ideas?

```
    <form action="edit.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[1] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row[2] ?>" />

<!-- this is the required href to trigger overlay -->
    <a href="edit.php" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">

         <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>

    </a>

    </form>

<div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay"> 

<!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag --> 
<div class="contentWrap"></div> 

</div> 

<!-- make all links with the 'rel' attribute open overlays --> 
<script> 

$(function() {

    // if the function argument is given to overlay,
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'darkred',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is jQuery  Tools Overlay ?? Are you talking about jQuery UI? Is this source code edit.php or ?

Comment: Oh jQuery tool by flowplayer ... http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the question but this is possibly what you are looking for...

You need to either pass the ID in the url and look up the data serverside or pass all the data in the url like so

```
<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row[1] ?>&name="<?php echo $row[2] ?>" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">
```

Comment: in the example above do you mean i need to switch to `$_GET`?

Comment: Yes you would need to do that,  that is the simplest method, in this case. Edits forms are often requested with get, rather than post, since you are not changing the data.

Comment: just to be sure -- so you're saying I would need to actually remove the `<form>` element and send everything via `href`  and `$_GET`? -- thanks for the help!

Comment: yeap, thats what you would do

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to store name id and all that stuff in $_SESSION in php. Then info.php would save it and edit php would read it.